# How to install the zip extension on MacOS when PHP is already installed?

Tags: php, zip, installation, php-7

I have PHP 7.1.12 installed on my Mac. I need to install Prestashop but it requires the Zip extension. Is it possible to install the Zip extension for PHP without completely reinstalling PHP (and recompiling it) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Install macports then run:

```
sudo port install php71-zip
```